# Not able to run bitcoinj wallettemplate example using testnet3

Tags: bitcoinj

When I run the bitcoinj example with MainNetParams it works fine but when I try to run with testnet3 I get the following error in the console.Please guide me.

```
11:06:55 21 DRMWorkaround.maybeDisableExportControls: Failed to deactivate AES-256 barrier logic, Tor mode/BIP38 decryption may crash if this JVM requires it: Can not set static final boolean field javax.crypto.JceSecurity.isRestricted to (boolean)false
11:06:56 21 AbstractBlockChain.addWallet: Wallet/chain height mismatch: -1 vs 1147104
11:06:56 21 AbstractBlockChain.addWallet: Hashes: null vs 0000000000000a1c34e39a6ff2c396c9c4cede41897c7475b47438ef94a7e6e0
11:06:56 25 PeerGroup$8.run: Starting ...
11:06:56 25 PeerGroup$8.run: Starting Tor/Orchid ...
11:06:56 25 TorClient.start: Starting Orchid (version: 1.0.0)
11:06:56 26 DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore: Loading cached network information from disk
11:06:56 26 DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore: Loading certificates
11:06:56 27 CircuitCreationTask.checkCircuitsForCreation: Cannot build circuits because we don't have enough directory information
11:06:56 26 DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore: Loading consensus
11:06:56 26 ConsensusDocumentImpl.verifySingleAuthority: Consensus signed by unrecognized directory authority: 0232af901c31a04ee9848595af9bb7620d4c5b2e
11:06:56 26 DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore: Loading microdescriptor cache
11:06:57 26 DirectoryImpl.loadFromStore: loading state file
11:06:59 20 KeyCrypterScrypt.deriveKey: Deriving key took 4.364 s for 32768 scrypt iterations.
11:06:59 20 WalletSetPasswordController.lambda$0: Background test key derivation took 4367msec
11:07:22 29 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:22 32 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:22 30 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:22 28 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:22 31 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:48 32 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:52 30 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:52 31 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:52 28 DirectoryDownloadTask$DownloadRouterDescriptorsTask.run: Failed to download router descriptors: Failed to open directory circuit
11:07:56 25 PeerGroup$8.run: Exception when starting up
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.bitcoinj.core.PeerGroup$8.run(PeerGroup.java:1146)
```

Comment: Can you paste little code so we can understand what are you trying to do.